# Can't install PyWin32 on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pywin32

I'm trying to run a project on google colab and I need to use PyWin32 (https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/), but I get the following error:

```
!pip install pywin32

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

Comment: What's the *OS*? or in *Python* console: `sys.platform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this application this Windows-only as I see in the part of 'Classifier' at https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/ only has Windows enviroment. And Colab's OS is Ubuntu. In addition, the list of packages for installation of pywin32 at https://pypi.org/simple/pywin32/ has no word related to Linux or Ubuntu. So may be you need to try another approach. 
 Other's question same to yours: [Error when installing pywin32 (on Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64579002/error-when-installing-pywin32-on-ubuntu)