# Use ExternalPythonOperator in Apache Airflow with a Windows venv on a Docker for Desktop setup

Tags: python, windows, docker, airflow, docker-desktop

I have a set of Python scripts for automating different tasks on a Windows environment, and most of these tasks make use of the `pywin32` library. Therefore, I need a python executable from a Windows venv in order to run these scripts.

I thought about using Apache Airflow to schedule the execution of these scripts and I installed it on my Windows machine using Docker for Desktop and the official production images. I have been trying to make `ExternalPythonOperator` use a test Windows venv that I set up and mount on to the airflow containers by referencing the python executable within this venv using `PATH_TO_PYTHON_BINARY`. To do so, I have created a volume to place all the venvs needed for the execution of these scripts, so these venvs can be accessed from the airflow container: `${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/venvs:/opt/airflow/venvs`.

For this example, I am trying to use `/opt/airflow/venvs/test_1`, so I set `PATH_TO_PYTHON_BINARY = '/opt/airflow/venvs/test_1/scripts/python.exe'`.

This is the test DAG I am trying to run:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import socket
from platform import platform
from airflow.models.dag import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import ExternalPythonOperator, PythonOperator

# Test callable
def test_function():
    print('This is a test callable.')
    print(f'Today is {datetime.today().date()}.')
    print(f'Execution started at {datetime.today().time()}'[:-6])
    print(f'The host is {socket.gethostname()}.')
    print(f'Running on {platform()}')
    print('End of the script.')

with DAG(
    "external-python",
    default_args={
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "email": ["myemail@email.com"],
        "email_on_failure": False,
        "email_on_retry": False,
        "retries": 0,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    },
    description="Test DAG",
    schedule=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["python-script"],
) as dag:
    # First task is to execute test_function using PythonOperator to see if code works correctly
    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="python-operator",
        python_callable=test_function,
        retries=0)

    # Second task is to execute test_function using ExternalPythonOperator
    PATH_TO_PYTHON_BINARY = '/opt/airflow/venvs/test_1/scripts/python.exe'
    t2 = ExternalPythonOperator(
        task_id="external-python-operator",
        depends_on_past=False,
        python_callable=test_function,
        python=PATH_TO_PYTHON_BINARY,
        retries=0,
    )

    t1.set_downstream(t2)
```

Running this DAG results in a successfull run of the first task, which prints the following results:

```
[2023-12-26, 14:22:50 CET] {logging_mixin.py:188} INFO - This is a test script.
[2023-12-26, 14:22:50 CET] {logging_mixin.py:188} INFO - Today is 2023-12-26.
[2023-12-26, 14:22:50 CET] {logging_mixin.py:188} INFO - Execution started at 13:22:50.
[2023-12-26, 14:22:50 CET] {logging_mixin.py:188} INFO - The host is f991b6d7f20a.
[2023-12-26, 14:22:50 CET] {logging_mixin.py:188} INFO - Running on Linux-5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.34
[2023-12-26, 14:22:50 CET] {logging_mixin.py:188} INFO - End of the script
```

However, the second task fails and returns the following error:

```
[2023-12-26, 14:22:51 CET] {taskinstance.py:2699} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 855, in _get_python_version_from_environment
    result = subprocess.check_output([self.python, "--version"], text=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/airflow/venvs/test_1/scripts/python.exe', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 433, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 400, in execute
    return super().execute(context=serializable_context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 199, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 839, in execute_callable
    python_version_as_list_of_strings = self._get_python_version_from_environment()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 858, in _get_python_version_from_environment
    raise ValueError(f"Error while executing {self.python}: {e}")
ValueError: Error while executing /opt/***/venvs/test_1/scripts/python.exe: Command '['/opt/***/venvs/test_1/scripts/python.exe', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Long story short: **can I use a Windows venv to execute a Python callable in Apache Airflow** or am I trying to do the impossible? I am pretty new using Apache Airflow and I could not find any information about Windows venvs in the official documentation. I did not find any similar question either, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you can `import pywin32` even in linux based systems, so even if the continer where you host Airflow is based on a Linux distro you can pip install it, this would be the fastest and easiest solution, to do it you can install it manually you can run `docker ps` to check your containers IDs or names, and then `docker exec -t -i mycontainer /bin/bash` and `pip install pywin32`

Or you can add a requirements.txt that installs all the dependencies, you should modify your `docker-compose` cahnging:

```
_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
```

And your `Docker file` adding:

```
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Alternatively if you are set to execute your scripts from a virtual environment you can also do that, but it involves a bit of networking, you can set up an SSH server in your container and then use the [SSHOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-ssh/stable/_api/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh/index.html) to launch commands to other hosts (or containers), you can see this othe post for a reference: [How to execute command from one docker container to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035543/how-to-execute-command-from-one-docker-container-to-another/63690421#63690421)

I have never used it myself but as a last resort you can also use the [PythonVirtualenvOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#pythonvirtualenvoperator), I believe you have the same use case.

Hope it helps!

Comment: As far as I know you can't pip install nor use pywin32 on a linux based system because this library contains utilities to access the win32 API (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64579002/error-when-installing-pywin32-on-ubuntu for example), that is why I was trying to make Apache Airflow use a venv hosted on my Windows machine. 
The second option however looks promising, I will give it a try. Thanks for the response!